# How can i pull out all metrics for a resource in Azure using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-metrics-advisor

I am at the moment running the following Powershell scipt pull out metrics from Azure

` #login to azure and set context

```
 $Resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceName <appservicename> -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup> -       ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites"
 $ResourceID = $Resource.ResourceId

 $MetricsDefinition = Get-AzMetricDefinition -ResourceId $ResourceID
 $MetricsDefinitionHash = @{}
 $MetricsDefinition | % {
 $Name = $_.Name
 $Unit = $_.Unit
 $MetricsDefinitionHash.Add($Name,$Unit) 
 }
 $TotalResult = @()
 
  $Metrics = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceID -StartTime (Get-date).AddHours(-24) -TimeGrain       00:01:00

  $Metrics | % {
  if($_.Data -ne $null)
  { 
  $Calc, $metricName, $Result = $Null
  $i=0;
  $MetricName = $_.Name
  $_.Data | % {
  $calc += $_.Average
  $i++
 } 
 $Result = $Calc/$i
 $MetricUnit = $MetricsDefinitionHash["$MetricName"]

 $MetricResult = New-Object PSObject
 $MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricName $metricName
 $MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricValue $Result
 $MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricUnit $MetricUnit
 $TotalResult += $MetricResult
 }
 }
```

`

I expected a result of
MetricName                  MetricValue                 MetricUnit
AverageResponseTime         0.7866443                   Seconds
AverageMemoryWorkingSet     80747385.625                Bytes
MemoryWorkingSet
Http5xx
Http4xx
Http406
Http404
Http403
Http401
Http3xx                     0
Http2xx                     0
BytesSent                  4699.123
BytesReceived              7.8
Requests                   9.4444
CpuTime                    0.1111

I have left some values empty , but you get the idea.
The issue is im only getting  CpuTime .
Any ideas on why i would only be getting that ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried in my environments to get those metrics

```
$Resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceName “metricdemoapp” -ResourceGroupName “xxx”       -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites"
 $ResourceID = $Resource.ResourceId
```

$Metrics = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceID -StartTime (Get-date).AddHours(-24) -TimeGrain       00:01:00

***`The above returns variable $Metrics returns only metrics of CpuTime  and its details  like Id, name, type ,unit ,Data,timeseries  as it is the first metric that appears`***

With Id         :   `/subscriptions/xxxxxx23f/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/metricdemoapp/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/CpuTime`

[image]

After Checking the supported metrics in portal in my case , web app service

[image]

when tried with other metric name, got the units as required.

[image]

- Where as below command  for definition gives details of all metrics along with details one by one.

  $MetricsDefinition = Get-AzMetricDefinition  -ResourceId $ResourceID
  $MetricsDefinition

[image]

***Powershell :***

```
$Resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceName “metricdemoapp” -ResourceGroupName “xxx”       -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites"
 $ResourceID = $Resource.ResourceId

$MetricsDefinition = Get-AzMetricDefinition  -ResourceId $ResourceID
$MetricsDefinition


$i=0
foreach($metric in $MetricsDefinition)
{
$MetricName=$MetricsDefinition.Name.Value[$i]
$MetricDetails= Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceID  -MetricName  $MetricName
$MetricDataValue=$MetricDetails.Data
$Timestamp=$MetricDetails.Data.TimeStamp
$Average=$MetricDetails.Data.Average




$mCount=$MetricName.Value.Count
$count=$mCount-1

$MetricUnit=$metric.Unit
$MetricUnit

$MetricValue=$MetricName.Value
$MetricValue

$MetricResult = New-Object PSObject
 $MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricName $MetricName

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricUnit $MetricUnit

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricDetails $MetricDetails

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricDataValue $MetricDataValue

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty TimeStamp  $Timestamp

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty  Average $Average


 $MetricResult



$i++


}
```

**Output:**

***Will be something like:***

```
MetricName      : CpuTime
MetricUnit      : Seconds
MetricDetails   : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricNoDetails
MetricDataValue : {Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricValue, Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricValue, Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricValue, 
                  Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricValue…}
TimeStamp       : {11/24/2022 6:23:00 AM, 11/24/2022 6:24:00 AM, 11/24/2022 6:25:00 AM, 11/24/2022 6:26:00 AM…}
Average         : {$null, $null, $null, $null…}
```

And continues for every metric like below

[image]

Where AverageResponseTime is one of the metrics you can see

[image]

---

**EDIT: 28/11/2022**

[image]

**Try adding aggregation type Average** lie `$MetricDetails= Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceID  -MetricName  $MetricName -AggregationType Average -TimeGrain 06:00:00`

```
$MetricsDefinition = Get-AzMetricDefinition  -ResourceId $ResourceID


$i=0
foreach($metric in $MetricsDefinition)
{
$MetricName=$MetricsDefinition.Name.Value[$i]
$MetricDetails= Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceID  -MetricName  $MetricName -AggregationType Average -TimeGrain 06:00:00



$MetricDataValue=$MetricDetails.Data
$Timestamp=$MetricDetails.Data.TimeStamp
$Average=$MetricDetails.Data.Average




$mCount=$MetricName.Value.Count
$count=$mCount-1

$MetricUnit=$metric.Unit
$MetricUnit

$MetricValue=$MetricName.Value
$MetricValue

$MetricResult = New-Object PSObject
 $MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricName $MetricName

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricUnit $MetricUnit

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricDetails $MetricDetails

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty MetricDataValue $MetricDataValue

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty TimeStamp  $Timestamp

$MetricResult | add-member Noteproperty  Average $Average


 $MetricResult



$i++


}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to suggest you PSCustomObject instead of New-Object PSObject. PSCustomObject is available from PS V3 and it comparatively faster. Here is the link for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: So the modified script you added would output all metrics and then in order to retrieve the average value and do a check for example if Http3xxx count is greater than 2 , I would need to traverse each or can i put it in a table ?

Comment: or in a json object and since there are 4 average values do i retrieve the highest ?

Comment: Try getting metric details for only Average aggregation type if only that is required ` $MetricDetails =Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceID   -MetricName "Threads" -AggregationType Average -TimeGrain 06:00:00  `

Comment: please check the edit , to get single average value for each metric , from which you can calculate result for all metrics together.